# Error 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: javascript

tengo este codigo al momento de acceder a la url me marca el erro 401 (Unauthorized) al parecer no recibe el usuario y la contraseña ya que para acceder a la pagina necesito autenticarme, ya que estoy haciendo una petición donde ingreso la curp y me debe de arrojar los datos de la persona. Gracias

```
var usr = "usuario",
  pwd = "contraseña",
  server = "http://" + usr + ":" + pwd + "@wsrenapo.col.gob.mx/curp2",
  service = "CURP",
  method = "getInfo",
  call = server + "/" + service + "/" + method + "/" + CURP;                            

var jqxhr = $.get(call, function(data) {
  console.log (data);
  app.MsgBox("Correcto");
}, "json")
.fail(function() {              
  app.MsgBox("Ocurrió un error al intentar conectar con el servidor...");               
});
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que el protocolo http es el correcto? Estoy casi seguro que para http la sintaxis es dominio:puerto no usuario:contraseña

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de la versión de jQuery que estés usando la autenticación básica con http es enviando el usuario y contraseña como sigue:

```
var usr = "usuario",
  pwd = "contraseña",
  server = "http://wsrenapo.col.gob.mx/curp2",
  service = "CURP",
  method = "getInfo",
  call = server + "/" + service + "/" + method + "/" + curl;                            

var jqxhr = $.ajax({url: call, username: usr, password: pwd, method: 'GET'}, function(data) {
  console.log (data);
}, "json")
.fail(function() {              
  alert("Ocurrió un error al intentar conectar con el servidor...");               
});
```

Cuando sucede esto siempre es bueno recurrir a la documentación [oficial](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings). donde indica como enviar 'password' y 'username'

Cambie $.get por $.ajax porque siempre este expresa mejor las cosas cuando se hace mas que un GET (este es un GET con autenticación simple).